# auto-correlation in matlab

Tags: matlab

i want to ask about how to do auto-correlation function to every frame in  a sound wave by my hand not built in function i do a code and i don't know if it right or wrong so please help
also i want to get the pitch period

```
[sound,  Fs]= wavread('aa.wav');

subplot(5,1,1);plot (sound);title('The Orignal Wave')
frameSize= 10/10^3;
overlapSize= 5/10^3;

frameSize_samples = round(Fs*frameSize);
overlapSize_samples= round(overlapSize* Fs);

shift = frameSize_samples-overlapSize_samples;

nframes=ceil((length(sound)-frameSize_samples)/shift);

frames = zeros(nframes, frameSize_samples);
for i=1:nframes
      frames(i,:) = sound( ((i-1)*shift+ 1):((i-1)*shift+ frameSize_samples) )';
end

subplot(5,1,2);plot (frames(:));title(' Wave after framing')


w = rectwin(frameSize_samples)';

frames1 = zeros(nframes, frameSize_samples);

 for i=1:nframes
     frames1(i,:)=(frames(i,:).*w);
 end

 %/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 % calc energy
 numSamples = length(sound);
 energy = zeros(1,nframes);  
 for frame = 1:nframes   
     energy(frame) = sum(frames1(frame).^2);             %# Calculate frame energy
 end
 subplot(5,1,3);plot (energy(:));title(' Energy')


 % calc autocorrelation


 autocorrelation = zeros(1,nframes);
 for i=1:nframes
     for k = 0:frameSize_samples
         autocorrelation(i,:)= sum(frames(i)*frames(i+k));
     end
 end


 subplot(5,1,4);plot (autocorrelation(:));title(' autocorrelation')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the equation [here](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Sound__Autocorrelate___.html). The autocorrelation equation looks fine. But I am confused by `frames`. You define it as a 2-D matrix, but then index it linearly (`frames(i)`).

Also, the for loop `for k=0:frameSize_samples` is not doing anything; you are assigning the same variable `autocorrelation(i, :)` in every iteration, so it will be overwritten.

Comment: i understand what an auto-correlation function  do but i can't really do it on matlab all what i want to have a matrix of autocorrelation every row represents in it the auto-correlation of one frame by multiplying the frame by its shifted versions by the length of the frame so i think the matrix will be autocorrelation = zeros(nframes, frameSize_samples);